# Convergence of oscillatory integral to real number

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, complex-integration

Given the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-s(\omega(t)+\mathrm{i}\sigma(t))}$$
with $\omega(t)\geq0$ and $\omega(t)\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, is it possible to choose a $\sigma(t)$ such that it converges to a real value larger than zero for $s\to\infty$? I.e. such that
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-s(\omega(t)+\mathrm{i}\sigma(t))}=\text{const.}>0$$
I'm particularly interested in the case when $\omega$ is a polynomial of an even order.

Comment: For $\sigma\equiv 0$ we have a real integrand, hence a real integral that converges to zero for $s\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the case where the constant is $>0$